# Crash when setText on TextView

Tags: android, textview, settext

when I try to generate this code, this error:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference.

That is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements   View.OnTouchListener{
private Tablero fondo;
int x;
int y;
private boolean activo = true;
int intento = 10;
String numerointentos;


     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    TextView Tiradas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Intentos) ;
    numerointentos = Integer.toString(intento);
    Tiradas.setText(numerointentos);

    fondo = new Tablero(this);
    fondo.setOnTouchListener(this);
    linearLayout1.addView(fondo);
    fondo.casillas = new Casilla[8][8];
    for (int f = 0; f < 8; f++){
        for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++){
            fondo.casillas[f][c] = new Casilla();
        }
    }
```

And this is the .xml code:

```
<?xml version= "1.01" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width= "fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:weightSum="1">
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/reiniciar"
    android:id="@+id/btnReiniciar"
    android:onClick="presionado"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

 <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:id="@+id/Intentos"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Obviously there is more code and code and clases, but that is the unique that contains the setText.

And another question. If I want to modify the value of the TextView in another public voids or methods what should I do?

I appreciate your help guys, I searched for anwsers on that web but I can't solve it. I don't know the reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the declaration of the `TextView` as the class' property

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public TextView Tiradas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView( ... );

        Tiradas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Intentos);
        Tiradas.setText(numerointentos);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Make sure that you have no other variants of `activity_main.xml` file (such as for landscape or bigger screen size). If you have, add the missing views to that layout file.

Because [findViewById(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) will return `null` if the view is not found in the referenced layout.

Comment: Hi, I'm going to add what I have before @override, look it, because i don't have tha same public class. Thanks!

Comment: There is the new code, thanks!

Comment: it's the same :) as long as the `Tiradas` variable is the class' variable (global variable) (not as local variable inside the `onCreate` method, then the NPE error will not occur if you're doing `setText` inside `onCreate`. I have updated my code btw, hope this helps

Comment: Hi I tried to do like you and keeps crashing at the same point. Thanks!

Comment: from [findViewById documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)), it looks like the view is not found. Are you sure that `activity_main` xml layout file has a view with id `Intentos` ? or probably you're referencing another layout instead. Also make sure that you have no other varians of `activity_main` xml file (for landscape or bigger screen size)

Comment: THANKS!! That's IT! I don't know why I have the folder /layout/activity_main.xml and /layout-v21/activity:main.xml
Only the file of /layout was modified. Now it Works! THANKS A LOT to all!

Comment: wohoo :D please upvote and mark my answer as accepted answer. I have edited my answer that solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try making text view a global variable? Then you can access that text field in other functions too.

Like this.

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
       {
    TextView Tiradas;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManAger.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout)       findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    Tiradas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Intentos) ;
    numerointentos = Integer.toString(intento);
    Tiradas.setText(numerointentos);
    fondo = new Tablero(this);
}
}`

Comment: Hi Snippy, thanks for your answer but, I'm new on Java and Android, so what do you mean with the Logcat? 
Thanks and sorry!

Comment: Log cat is the out put terminal that Android Studio uses to display output.

Comment: Hi Snippy, but I don't have the same public class, take a look about the new code and thanks! I don't know if I can change the public class.